# Jenkins Pipeline Failing with error - <PID> killed ./mvnw test

Tags: unix, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a simple pipeline which was running file untill last time I checked. But now  its suddenly failing for any maven stage with the following error. Only the stage ./mvnw clean works fine.

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ProjectID@tmp/durable-ce5247e8/script.sh: line 2: 31370 Killed                  ./mvnw test
```

I tried looking at the logs for the job as well as the logs at /var/log/jenkins but I do not see anything detailed. I also tried running the mvnw command with -x, but this error does not seem to be coming from the mvn command itself. I could also confirm that the code compiles/builds fine on my local machine as well as on the jenkins server if ran manually.

I am relatively new to unix/jenkins/pipeline environment and I am clueless as to where should I look for troubleshooting. Has anyone ever encountered such situation? Appreciate any clue for troubleshooting the issue.

Thanks a lot,

Adding further investigation:

To get around this issue, did the following steps. 
 1. stopped Jenkins service
 2. Restarted the EC2 instance hosting jenkins. (Did it a couple of times)
 3. Verified that the Jenkins service is stopped. 
 4. Then ran the top command to see the CPU usage and noticed a strange thing. There was a process with command debug running. This process was owned by the user jenkins. 
 5. I looked around on internet to see if I find anything on this debug command but with no luck.
 6. I killed it to see if that helps, But to my serprise, this did not help rather the situation is now worse and the top command "top -U jenkins" now gives following result (and the number of processes are ever growing)

```
top - 15:15:09 up  1:39,  1 user,  load average: 191.30, 175.24, 135.72
Tasks: 189 total,   3 running, 159 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 82.7%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si, 
17.1%st 
Mem:   4040060k total,   822672k used,  3217388k free,    42128k buffers
Swap:  4194300k total,        0k used,  4194300k free,   236476k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  
COMMAND
6344 jenkins   20   0  384m 6764 2784 S  2.3  0.2   3:27.28 debug
6592 jenkins   20   0  384m 6880 2896 S  2.3  0.2   2:22.55 debug
6770 jenkins   20   0  384m 6860 2872 S  2.3  0.2   2:00.24 debug
7040 jenkins   20   0  384m 6760 2776 S  2.3  0.2   1:31.72 debug
7115 jenkins   20   0  384m 6864 2880 S  2.3  0.2   1:26.05 debug
7254 jenkins   20   0  384m 6828 2840 S  2.3  0.2   1:16.73 debug
7375 jenkins   20   0  384m 6812 2828 S  2.3  0.2   1:08.34 debug
7464 jenkins   20   0  384m 6864 2880 S  2.3  0.2   1:04.63 debug
7600 jenkins   20   0  320m 6852 2868 S  2.3  0.2   0:57.73 debug
7668 jenkins   20   0  320m 6780 2800 S  2.3  0.2   0:54.29 debug
7797 jenkins   20   0  320m 6756 2776 S  2.3  0.2   0:48.62 debug
7798 jenkins   20   0  320m 6776 2792 S  2.3  0.2   0:48.68 debug
7872 jenkins   20   0  320m 6852 2868 S  2.3  0.2   0:45.91 debug
7929 jenkins   20   0  320m 6756 2776 S  2.3  0.2   0:43.38 debug
8005 jenkins   20   0  320m 6808 2828 S  2.3  0.2   0:40.94 debug
8012 jenkins   20   0  320m 6884 2896 S  2.3  0.2   0:40.91 debug
8073 jenkins   20   0  320m 6852 2868 S  2.3  0.2   0:38.44 debug
6271 jenkins   20   0  384m 6852 2868 S  2.1  0.2   4:28.22 debug
6278 jenkins   20   0  384m 6752 2772 S  2.1  0.2   4:28.42 debug
6434 jenkins   20   0  384m 6828 2844 S  2.1  0.2   2:57.29 debug
6544 jenkins   20   0  384m 6860 2880 S  2.1  0.2   2:37.40 debug
6692 jenkins   20   0  384m 6784 2800 S  2.1  0.2   2:10.43 debug
6745 jenkins   20   0  384m 6856 2872 S  2.1  0.2   2:00.54 debug
6887 jenkins   20   0  384m 6824 2840 S  2.1  0.2   1:44.45 debug
6909 jenkins   20   0  384m 6812 2828 S  2.1  0.2   1:44.33 debug
6973 jenkins   20   0  384m 6852 2872 S  2.1  0.2   1:37.80 debug
7253 jenkins   20   0  384m 6812 2828 S  2.1  0.2   1:16.45 debug
7321 jenkins   20   0  320m 6828 2844 S  2.1  0.2   1:12.39 debug
7396 jenkins   20   0  384m 6800 2816 S  2.1  0.2   1:08.26 debug
7451 jenkins   20   0  320m 6880 2896 S  2.1  0.2   1:04.73 debug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue was happening because the CPU was getting overworked because of a mining attack on our server. This server had to be killed and rebuilt. The debug process shown in the above logs against the jenkins user is the mining script.